# Issues with the App_code folder

Tags: asp.net

I created an application which is using classes from App_Code.

I have now added this application as a subfolder to an existing application. So there are App_Code now one in the root and one in the sub-folder.

I want to find out how do I make my app in the subfolder be able to recognize files kept in teh App_Code of the subfolder.

Comment: Are you saying you have two website projects in Visual Studio, each with their own App_Code folder? Or do you have one project with folders?

Comment: I created one website 'A' with its own app_code folder. Then i added 'A' to another website 'B' as a subfolder. B also contains a App_Code. I cannot merge the two since both have some classes with the same name.

Comment: Wait you're trying to merge two websites together? There isn't an easy way to do this. In all honesty I would move most of the stuff in App_Code that isn't UI related into Library projects so your other projects can reference them.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider moving all of your code out of App_Code (and the /OldProject/App_Code) folders and into a new Class Library Project. Put the code from OldProject into one namespace, and the code from NewProject into a different namespace (avoids the duplicate name problem). Then add references to the new project dll and namespace to the web app where appropriate (doing this will also enable you to Unit Test your code, something that is near impossible to do when the code is in App_Code).

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to go through website B's app_code folder and create a new namespace for these classes. Then move all of the files into one app_code folder so that everything gets complied down to one assembly during runtime. The framework should be able to figure things out at that time.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris but that didn't work me, Looks like I have to do what Yaakov suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think that codeSubDirectories is used only when using C# and VB.NET in the same project. For ex. your website is in C# but in but you want to use also VB.NET code. This is valid only for websites though and not for web application projects.

[using c# and vb in the same web project](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/02/28/14002.aspx)

But if for ex. WebsiteA is located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebsiteA and you want the WebsiteB to have the location C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebsiteA\WebsiteB then both WebsiteA and Website B should be configured as virtual directories in IIS.

If you were talking about sharing the same logic between applications, then you should wrap the whole logic in a class library and reference it to the projects.